# Iterate PHP Array and validate data

Tags: php, arrays, validation

**Explanation:**

Using PHP, I have a form that lets users create outgoing orders.

The user is able to select what inventory item they would like to send in a specific box # to a specific customer.

I would like to add validation to this form because the user should not be able to select 2 different customers for the same box #.

Example:

```
Person A -> Item A -> Box 1
Person A -> Item B -> Box 1
Person B -> Item C -> Box 2
Person B -> Item D -> Box 1 //!! <- This should not be possible because                                    
Person C -> Item E -> Box 3        //Person A is already using Box #1.
```

When the form is submitted I am creating an array like this:

```
$data = (object) array
    (
    array (
        "customer" => "Person A",
        "item" => "Item A",
        "box" => "Box 1"
    ),
    array (
        "customer" => "Person A",
        "item" => "Item B",
        "box" => "Box 1"
    ),
    array (
        "customer" => "Person B",
        "item" => "Item C",
        "box" => "Box 2"
    ),
    array (
        "customer" => "Person B",
        "item" => "Item D",
        "box" => "Box 1"
    ),
    array (
        "customer" => "Person C",
        "item" => "Item E",
        "box" => "Box 3"
    )

);
```

**Question:**

How do I go about iterating through this array to validate that every person has their own Box #?

This is what I am trying but I am getting stuck:

```
$temp_arr = (object) array();

foreach($data as $row){

    if(!property_exists($temp_arr, $row['customer'])){
      $temp_arr->$row['customer'] = array();
    };

    //Load the boxes into the correct customer array
    if(in_array($row['box'], $temp_arr->$row['customer'])){
        //Duplicate 
    } else {
      array_push($temp_arr->$row['customer'], $row['box']);
    }

}
```

Comment: so if a person has an item but using a taken box # that item should go to the user with the noted box #?

Comment: If a box is already taken, the validation ends and the user is warned that they cannot use 2 customers for the same box #

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
   $used_boxes = array();
   $valid_data = array();
   foreach($data as $row){
       if(!in_array($used_boxes)){
          //Box not used
          $valid_data[$row['customer']] = $row['box'];
          $used_boxes[] = $row['box'] 
       }else{
          //Box already used
       } 
   }
   var_dump($valid_data);
```